# SortedBiTreeMultimap data structure in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, guava, treemap

Is there any Java library with TreeMap-like data structure which also supports all of these:

- **lookup by value** (like Guava's BiMap)
- possibility of **non-unique keys** as well as non unique values (like Guava's Multimap)
- keeps track of **sorted values** as well as sorted keys

If it exists, it would probaby be called SortedBiTreeMultimap, or similar :)

This can be produced using a few data structures together, but I never took time to unite them in one nice class, so I was wondering if someone else has done it already.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for a "Graph". You might be interested in this [slightly similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578029/what-is-the-best-guava-google-collection-api-to-represent-direct-or-inverse-re) asked a while ago, as well as [this discussion thread](http://groups.google.com/group/guava-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1548b829495a07eb) on BiMultimaps / Graphs. Google has a BiMultimap in its internal code base, but they haven't yet decided whether to open source it.

Comment: Thanks for an answer! Yes, a sort of graph... *graph* would be *BiMultimap<T,T>* and I am looking for *BiMultimap<T,S>*, that also has keys sorted, therefore *Tree* implementation. I once implemented it as two TreeMaps with Sets as values, but it was a little ugly code...

Comment: A Guava BiHashMap just wraps two HashMaps. Your own code need not be any uglier than that. It's not magically beautiful just because it came from Google :).